# Can I enter the US with a visa issued outside my home country?

Tags: visas, usa

I was just wondering if it's possible for me to enter the United States with a US visa that is issued outside of India(My home country).I studied and worked in Canada for over 5 years and I applied for a US visitor visa in 2014 and I was approved and visited the US a few times for commercial deliveries and shopping. Now the visa is valid until 2024 and I want to know if the CBP will create problems for me since the issuing post in my visa is Ottawa instead of a city in India. I would like to attend the E3 gaming convention next year in LA :3

**Bigger question:** Will the Airline allow me to board the flight since they can be extremely picky.

Comment: It's quite normal for a visa to be issued in your country of residence not in your country of citizenship.

Comment: AFAIK airline guidance says absolutely nothing about checking the post that issued a visa or passport.

Comment: Why would this possibly be a problem?

Comment: I can't specifically address the US but I have entered many countries with visas issued from places other than where I lived.  I would think if it was going to be an issue they would refuse to issue it in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

If you have a multiple entry B1 (visitor) visa, and I believe they grant those for 10 years now, I don't see why they would refuse you entry (assuming there are no other red flags). A visa is a visa, if it's valid and your passport is valid, it should be no problem.
You say you visited the US before, why is this a problem now ?

The same goes for the airline, they're required to check you're legally allowed to enter your destination country and by way of your visa, you are.

You mention "commercial deliveries", if you have a business visa this may be problematic at the border if your intent is tourism. It's a little arbitrary at this point, I've seen a friend granted entry for tourism while on a business visa. But I'd say it's more risky than a regular tourist visa

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually it's a B1/B2 visa. So it's both Business and Tourism. Funny thing is that on the land border, they are really careless. So they allowed me to enter the US with a Tourist i-94 card for doing business deliveries. And most of my entries aren't even lodged since it's a land border. But then again, there is nothing on my profile that shows I have violated my visa conditions. So I hope that they won't create a big show over it. More than that I'll be carrying my return ticket and hotel reservs,etc.

Comment: Edit: I actually entered the US from Canada, never from India.

Comment: I second this, regardless where the visa issued, as long as it is valid they will let you in. Personal experience here.

Answer (score 2):

Both my passport and my US visa were issued in a country in which I am not a resident, and which is not related to my nationality.

It has made no difference to my entries to the US. A visa is a visa.