# Dual nationality and ESTA

Tags: usa, esta, dual-nationality

I am a French/Australian citizen, currently living in France. I want to use my Australian passport to travel in the USA because my French passport is not electronic.

Can I enter the US on an Australian passport even if I live in France knowing that I am a dual citizen?

Comment: I'm sure US officials are used to dealing with people who live in one place but are citizens of another, that should not be a problem for you, it's a very common scenario

Comment: [Here's](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56462/can-i-enter-the-us-with-a-visa-issued-outside-my-home-country/56463#56463) a similar scenario to yours

Answer (score 7):

US immigration <s>doesn't need to know you're a dual citizen.  Even if they do, they</s> won't care which passport you choose to use.  The US government even says you can just choose which passport to use (https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1096/~/esta---eligible-passport,-country-of-issuance,-citizenship).

The fact that you live in France does not mean that the US will require you to travel as a French citizen.  The only country where you must present yourself as a French citizen is France.

It is fine to leave France with your French passport and enter the US with your Australian.  In short, don't worry about it.

EDIT: It has come to my attention that the ESTA application asks you to disclose all of your citizenships.  So the statement that "US immigration doesn't need to know you're a dual citizen" is not true.

Comment: (+1) Even France does not care all that much I think.

Comment: I suppose not.  Most European countries seem to be far more, well, @Relaxed about this than the US.  But they could be stricter about it if they wanted to.  It just occurred to me, however, with the Pope in town, what about dual nationals who are also heads of state?  A head of state is required to apply for an A visa, even for unofficial travel.  But could the former German pope have followed the ESTA advice and chosen to travel on his German passport, seeking a visa waiver?

Comment: Since immigration authorities in the Schengen area use entry and exit stamps in the passport alone to document the travel history of non-EEA citizens, a dual EEA/non-EEA citizen will most likely run himself into a lot of unnecessary hazzle if he uses his non-EEA passport to enter or exit the Schengen area, at least if he is not consequently using one of the passports or if using the non-EEA passport not obeying the time limits for short term visitors.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo That is true in principle, although I suspect that "a lot" is relative.  If the traveller can convincingly demonstrate EEA nationality despite having initially presented a non-EEA passport, I suspect the hassle might actually be fairly minimal.

Comment: @phoog If you demonstrate your EEA nationality, which you for most practical purposes can do only by presenting an EEA passport or id card, are you then crossing the external Schengen border with your 3rd country or with your EEA travel document?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I'm coming at this from the point of view of someone who believes they must use the same passport for the entire trip.  Since the US requires using the US passport, they present the US passport upon return to France.  If they have stamps indicating a longer-than-90-day stay, hassle ensues.  If they have an ID card, the hassle is avoided.  If they have some other evidence of citizenship aside from an ID card or passport, hassle is limited to establishing their citizenship using an improper document.  Depending on the document, this may be more or less hassle.

Comment: @phoog I am not sure how Schengen immigration officers handle unnecessarily stamped travel documents of dual citizens. Assume the US/EEA citizens enters the Schengen area with a US passport, gets stamped in and stays more than the allowed 90 days. If he at this point leaves the Schengen area using an additional document providing his EEA citizenship, he can't be regularly stamped out, since the entry/exit stamps won't match. Not stamping is also not an option, since it will indicate leaving the Schengen area illegaly.

Comment: Having an unreasonable 'stamp history' from the Schengen area, may of course also be a problem when being in contact with immigration officers from a completely different country if they for some reason are interested in your previous travel history, e.g. in connection with a visa application or similar.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo EU/EEA citizens have the right to remain in the EU/EEA under freedom of movement.  It does not matter how they entered, nor whether they identified themselves as EU/EEA citizens at the time of entry.

Comment: @phoog Of course they do. Did I write something else?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I suppose not.  I must have misread "a completely different country," as I thought it meant "a different EU/EEA country"; I now suspect that you meant "a non-EU/EEA country."